# Index key/value for relationship with unique factory. What to choose?

Tags: neo4j

I'm using the following code to generate unique relationships

```
public Relationship createRelationshipTypeWithUniqueFactory(Index<Relationship> index,
        String indexableKey, final String indexableValue, 
final RelationshipType type, final Node start, final Node end) {

    UniqueFactory<Relationship> factory = new UniqueFactory.UniqueRelationshipFactory(index) {
        @Override
        protected Relationship create(Map<String, Object> properties) {
            Relationship r =  start.createRelationshipTo(end, type);
            return r;
        }
    };

    return factory.getOrCreate(indexableKey, indexableValue);
}
```

The factory requires me to pass a key and value (for the Index) so it can enforce the uniqueness of the relationship.
However, i'm not sure on how to build up the key + value.

Lets assume the following:

A - [knows] -> B (A knows B) where A and B are identified by the property email address

I  want this relation ship to be unique so that A has at most 1 KNOWN relationship with B of this type.
Also, this should prevent B from creating an additional relationship to A (as the KNOWS relationship is bi-directional).

What would the best value to choose? One of the e-mail addresses (for example the lexical sorted most important of the two)?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Cheers,

Erik

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cyphers `CREATE UNIQUE` feature, creating the relationship only if it doesn't exist no regarding the direction upon a second run, see http://console.neo4j.org/r/a4kc2k

```
START n=node:node_auto_index(name='Neo'), t= node:node_auto_index(name='The Architect') 
CREATE UNIQUE n-[r:SPEAKES_WITH]-t 
RETURN n AS Neo,r
```

Comment: To my knowledge, the cypher and java code provided is equivalent. Only, when using the java api you specifically have to set a index value for the relationship. What kind of they is the cypher version using under the hood?